# Filter / Match - Returning Not Found

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following Google Sheets formula, which returns where values in `Source!D1:D` are found in `Data!A1:A` :-

```
=sort(filter(Source!A1:AD, match(Source!D1:D, Data!A1:A, 0)),1,1)
```

Is it possible to have Sheets do the opposite, so return everything except where values in `Source!D1:D` are found in `Data!A1:A`?

I've tried

```
=sort(filter(Source!A1:AD, match(Source!D1:D, <>Data!A1:A, 0)),1,1)
```

but that returned an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
=sort(filter(Source!A1:AD, isna(match(Source!D1:D, Data!A1:A, 0))),1,1)
```